# No encuentro mi error en un proyecto usando Angularjs creando una directiva tipo elemento

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Buenas. Tengo una duda en un proyecto que estoy haciendo, en el cual utilizo angularjs y html. Lo que tengo que hacer es básicamente crear una directiva tipo elemento que contenga todo el contenido en una tabla, la cual dependa de un objeto en un controlador, el cual al inicializarse ya tenga un objeto de un arreglo de 30. Para eso debo una interfaz Web para que pueda convivir una tabla con las acciones de cada registro. Ya el código lo tengo listo, el problema es que no encuentro mi error. Lo he corregido ya varias veces y he intentado cambiar varias cosas a ver si así funciona pero nada. Mi error es que no se muestran los elementos del arreglo, que declaré ya en .js ni tampoco se agregan nuevos elementos al arreglo.

Lo que tengo como código es lo siguiente:

En **custom_directiva.html** tengo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<product-panels>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/todo.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">  
  </head>

<body>

<div class="tab">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Pagina principal')">Pagina principal</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Agregar productos')">Agregar productos</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Mostrar productos')">Mostrar productos</a>

</div>



<div id="Agregar productos" class="tabcontent">


<center>
     <form name="miFormulario" class="css-form">
       <hr>
       <h1 style="color:#01DF01"><img src="img/logo.jpg"/><br><br><br>Biotactex. Productos ecologicos C.A.</h1>
       <hr/>
       <b style="color:#5FB404">ID:<b/><br>
       <input type="text" ng-model="pro.Id" name="Id" placeholder="Id de producto" class="efecto" style="text-transform: uppercase;" required/>
       <br>
       <br>
       <b>Nombre:<b/><br>     
       <input type="text" ng-model="pro.Nombre" name="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre" class="efecto" style="text-transform: uppercase;" required/>
       <br>
       <br>
       <b>Descripción:<b/><br>
      <input type="text" ng-model="pro.Descripcion" name="Descripcion" placeholder="Descripción" class="efecto" required/>
       <br>
       <br>
       <b>Fecha:<b/><br>
       <input type="date" ng-model="pro.Fecha" name="Fecha" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" class="efecto" required/>
       <br>
       <br>
       <b>Precio:<b/><br>
       <input type="number" ng-model="pro.Precio" placeholder="Precio" class="efecto" name="Precio" ng-minlength="0" min=1 max=1000 required/><b> $<b/>
       <br>
       <br>
       <b>Cantidad:<b/><br>
       <input type="number" ng-model="pro.Cantidad" placeholder="Cant" class="efecto" name="Cantidad" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="51" min=1 max=50 required/>
       <br>
       <br>
       <b>Imagen:<b/><br>
         <select ng-model="pro.images" ng-options="imag for imag in imagenes" name="Imagen" class="efecto" required>
         <option value="">Elegir una opción</option>
         </select>
       <br>
       <br>
       <button ng-click="reset()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Limpiar</button>      
        <button type="submit"  ng:click="newUser()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Agregar</button>
        <br><br><br>
   </form>

   <style>
    .efecto
    {
        color:white;
        background:green;

    }
   </style>


</div>


<div id="Mostrar productos" class="tabcontent">

       <hr>
       <center><h3 style="color:#5FB404">Productos Biotactex. Compañia Ecologica de distribución de productos.</h3><center/>
       <hr/>
       <table class="container"> 
        <thead>
         <tr>

          <td align="center">Id</td>
          <td align="center">Nombre</td>
          <td align="center">Descripción</td>
          <td align="center">Imagen</td>
          <td align="center">Fecha</td>
          <td align="center">Precio</td>
          <td align="center">Cantidad</td>
          <td align="center">Acción</td>

        </tr>
         </thead>


            <tbody>

            <tr ng-repeat="prod in productos" ng-style="{color:($odd?'black':'green')}">
            <td style="text-transform: uppercase;" align="center">{{prod.Id}}</td>
            <td align="center">{{prod.Nombre}}</td>
            <td align="center">{{prod.Descripcion}}</td>
            <td align="center"><img src='{{prod.images}}'></td>
            <td align="center">{{prod.Fecha | date:"longDate"}}</td>
            <td align="center">{{prod.Precio}}</td>
            <td align="center">{{prod.Cantidad}}</td>

            <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="prod"/>Ocultar</td>
            <td><ng-if="prod"></td>


            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
            <hr>
            <tr>
            <button class="btn-warning" ng:click="removeItem($index)">Borrar fila</button>
            <button class="btn-warning" ng:click="borrar()">Borrar todo</button>
            <input class="btn-warning" type="submit" value="Mostrar Datos" ng-model="prod"/>    
            </tr>
            </hr>

</div>

<div id="Pagina principal" class="tabcontent">

<center><h2>Biotactex. Productos ecologicos C.A.</h2></center>


</div>





            </center>
  </body>
  </product-panels>
</html>
```

En **app2.js** tengo:

```
app.directive('productPanels', function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        templateUrl:'custom_directiva.html',
        controller: function($scope)
{
     $scope.imagenes=['img/bolsabio.jpg', 'img/eco.jpg', 'img/ecopaz.jpg','img/green-shopping.jpg','img/images.jpg','img/reciclaje.jpg'];
     $scope.pro = {};
     $scope.newUser = function()
     {
        $scope.productos.push($scope.pro);

    }

     $scope.reset = function() 
     {

        $scope.pro = { Id: '', nombre: '', descri:'', fecha:'',Precio:'', Cantidad:''};

      }
      $scope.borrar=function()
      {

          $scope.productos=[];

      }

      $scope.removeItem = function(custom_directiva) 
      {
        $scope.productos.splice(index,1);

      } 

   $scope.productos=[
      {
          Id:'4323432',
          Nombre:'Bolsas verdes',
          Descripcion:'Bolsas de plástico biodegradables',
          images:'img/bolsabio.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-10',
          Precio:20,
          Cantidad:10
      },
      {
          Id:'654645',
          Nombre:'Quimicos verdes',
          Descripcion:'Detergentes biodegradables',
          images:'img/eco.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

{
          Id:'764643',
          Nombre:'Aromaticos verdes',
          Descripcion:'Aromaticos que no emiten quimicos dañinos',
          images:'img/green-shopping.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

      {
          Id:'979089078',
          Nombre:'Bombillas verdes',
          Descripcion:'Bombillas de bajo consumo',
          images:'img/ecopaz.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

      {
          Id:'4352329',
          Nombre:'Productos desechables biodegrables',
          Descripcion:'Productos verdes no contaminantes',
          images:'img/images.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

      {
          Id:'3423432',
          Nombre:'Porta basura de reciclaje',
          Descripcion:'Para reciclar basura',
          images:'img/reciclaje.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-04-05',
          Precio:40,
          Cantidad:29
      },

          {
          Id:'4323432',
          Nombre:'Bolsas verdes',
          Descripcion:'Bolsas de plástico biodegradables',
          images:'img/bolsabio.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-10',
          Precio:20,
          Cantidad:10
      },
      {
          Id:'654645',
          Nombre:'Quimicos verdes',
          Descripcion:'Detergentes biodegradables',
          images:'img/eco.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

{
          Id:'764643',
          Nombre:'Aromaticos verdes',
          Descripcion:'Aromaticos que no emiten quimicos dañinos',
          images:'img/green-shopping.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

      {
          Id:'979089078',
          Nombre:'Bombillas verdes',
          Descripcion:'Bombillas de bajo consumo',
          images:'img/ecopaz.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

          {
          Id:'4323432',
          Nombre:'Bolsas verdes',
          Descripcion:'Bolsas de plástico biodegradables',
          images:'img/bolsabio.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-10',
          Precio:20,
          Cantidad:10
      },
      {
          Id:'654645',
          Nombre:'Quimicos verdes',
          Descripcion:'Detergentes biodegradables',
          images:'img/eco.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

{
          Id:'764643',
          Nombre:'Aromaticos verdes',
          Descripcion:'Aromaticos que no emiten quimicos dañinos',
          images:'img/green-shopping.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

      {
          Id:'979089078',
          Nombre:'Bombillas verdes',
          Descripcion:'Bombillas de bajo consumo',
          images:'img/ecopaz.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

          {
          Id:'4323432',
          Nombre:'Bolsas verdes',
          Descripcion:'Bolsas de plástico biodegradables',
          images:'img/bolsabio.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-10',
          Precio:20,
          Cantidad:10
      },
      {
          Id:'654645',
          Nombre:'Quimicos verdes',
          Descripcion:'Detergentes biodegradables',
          images:'img/eco.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

{
          Id:'764643',
          Nombre:'Aromaticos verdes',
          Descripcion:'Aromaticos que no emiten quimicos dañinos',
          images:'img/green-shopping.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

      {
          Id:'979089078',
          Nombre:'Bombillas verdes',
          Descripcion:'Bombillas de bajo consumo',
          images:'img/ecopaz.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

          {
          Id:'4323432',
          Nombre:'Bolsas verdes',
          Descripcion:'Bolsas de plástico biodegradables',
          images:'img/bolsabio.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-10',
          Precio:20,
          Cantidad:10
      },
      {
          Id:'654645',
          Nombre:'Quimicos verdes',
          Descripcion:'Detergentes biodegradables',
          images:'img/eco.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

{
          Id:'764643',
          Nombre:'Aromaticos verdes',
          Descripcion:'Aromaticos que no emiten quimicos dañinos',
          images:'img/green-shopping.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

      {
          Id:'979089078',
          Nombre:'Bombillas verdes',
          Descripcion:'Bombillas de bajo consumo',
          images:'img/ecopaz.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

          {
          Id:'4323432',
          Nombre:'Bolsas verdes',
          Descripcion:'Bolsas de plástico biodegradables',
          images:'img/bolsabio.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-10',
          Precio:20,
          Cantidad:10
      },
      {
          Id:'654645',
          Nombre:'Quimicos verdes',
          Descripcion:'Detergentes biodegradables',
          images:'img/eco.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

{
          Id:'764643',
          Nombre:'Aromaticos verdes',
          Descripcion:'Aromaticos que no emiten quimicos dañinos',
          images:'img/green-shopping.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

      {
          Id:'979089078',
          Nombre:'Bombillas verdes',
          Descripcion:'Bombillas de bajo consumo',
          images:'img/ecopaz.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

          {
          Id:'4323432',
          Nombre:'Bolsas verdes',
          Descripcion:'Bolsas de plástico biodegradables',
          images:'img/bolsabio.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-10',
          Precio:20,
          Cantidad:10
      },
      {
          Id:'654645',
          Nombre:'Quimicos verdes',
          Descripcion:'Detergentes biodegradables',
          images:'img/eco.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

{
          Id:'764643',
          Nombre:'Aromaticos verdes',
          Descripcion:'Aromaticos que no emiten quimicos dañinos',
          images:'img/green-shopping.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      },

      {
          Id:'979089078',
          Nombre:'Bombillas verdes',
          Descripcion:'Bombillas de bajo consumo',
          images:'img/ecopaz.jpg',
          Fecha:'2015-06-11',
          Precio:30,
          Cantidad:6
      }

      ]
}
        controllerAs:'panels'

    };


});
```

No he colocado el contenido de app.js ni del style.css porque estos si me corren bien y no se presenta el problema en ellos, sino en los que presente arriba. No sé si mi error esta en app.js o en custom_directiva.html, aunque creo que es talvez el url de la plantilla o algun código que tengo en la directiva que contiene al controlador. Agradecería mucho su respuesta, saludos

Answer (score 2):

Hay ciertos problemas con tu código. 
Realmente te sugiero que revises la documentación de angularjs o algun tutorial como los de Egghead. 
Los templates de las directivas generalmente no contienen los tags de HTML, HEAD o BODY... 
Intenta lo siguiente: 
 **custom_directiva.html**

```
<div>
<div id="Agregar productos" class="tabcontent">
    <center>
        <form name="miFormulario" class="css-form">
            <hr>
            <h1 style="color:#01DF01"><img src="img/logo.jpg"/><br/><br/> <br/>Biotactex. Productos ecologicos C.A.
            </h1>
            <hr/>
            <strong style="color:#5FB404">ID:</strong><br/>
            <input type="text" ng-model="pro.Id" name="Id" placeholder="Id de producto" class="efecto"
                   style="text-transform: uppercase;" required/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <strong>Nombre:</strong><br/>
            <input type="text" ng-model="pro.Nombre" name="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre" class="efecto"
                   style="text-transform: uppercase;" required/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <strong>Descripción:</strong><br/>
            <input type="text" ng-model="pro.Descripcion" name="Descripcion" placeholder="Descripción"
                   class="efecto" required/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <strong>Fecha:</strong><br/>
            <input type="date" ng-model="pro.Fecha" name="Fecha" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" class="efecto"
                   required/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <strong>Precio:</strong><br/>
            <input type="number" ng-model="pro.Precio" placeholder="Precio" class="efecto" name="Precio"
                   ng-minlength="0" min=1 max=1000 required/><strong> $</strong>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <strong>Cantidad:</strong><br/>
            <input type="number" ng-model="pro.Cantidad" placeholder="Cant" class="efecto" name="Cantidad"
                   ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="51" min=1 max=50 required/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <strong>Imagen:</strong><br/>
            <select ng-model="pro.images" ng-options="imag for imag in imagenes" name="Imagen" class="efecto"
                    required>
                <option value="">Elegir una opción</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <button ng-click="reset()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Limpiar</button>
            <button type="submit" ng-click="newUser()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Agregar</button>
            <br/><br/><br/>
        </form>
    </center>
</div>
<div id="Mostrar productos" class="tabcontent">
    <hr>
    <center><h3 style="color:#5FB404">Productos Biotactex. Compañia Ecologica de distribución de productos.</h3>
        <center/>
        <hr/>
        <table class="container">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">Id</td>
                <td align="center">Nombre</td>
                <td align="center">Descripción</td>
                <td align="center">Imagen</td>
                <td align="center">Fecha</td>
                <td align="center">Precio</td>
                <td align="center">Cantidad</td>
                <td align="center">Acción</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="prod in productos" ng-style="{color:($odd?'black':'green')}">
                <td style="text-transform: uppercase;" align="center">{{prod.Id}}</td>
                <td align="center">{{prod.Nombre}}</td>
                <td align="center">{{prod.Descripcion}}</td>
                <td align="center"><img src='{{prod.images}}'></td>
                <td align="center">{{prod.Fecha | date:"longDate"}}</td>
                <td align="center">{{prod.Precio}}</td>
                <td align="center">{{prod.Cantidad}}</td>
                <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="prod"/>Ocultar
                    <!-- La verdad que me imagino que quieres estas acciones aqui -->
                    <button class="btn-warning" ng-click="removeItem($index)">Borrar fila</button>
                    <button class="btn-warning" ng-click="borrar()">Borrar todo</button>
                    <input class="btn-warning" type="submit" value="Mostrar Datos" ng-model="prod"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div id="Pagina principal" class="tabcontent">
        <center><h2>Biotactex. Productos ecologicos C.A.</h2></center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y en donde vas a ocupar tu directiva, ahora sí, pones el tag custom:
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app2.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/todo.css">
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
  .efecto
  {
    color:white;
    background:green;
  }
  </style> 
</head>
<body>
  <div class="tab">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Pagina principal')">Pagina principal</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Agregar productos')">Agregar productos</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Mostrar productos')">Mostrar productos</a>
  </div>
  <product-panels></product-panels>
 </body>
</html>
```

Igualmente, si gustas exponer mejor lo que buscas lograr, con gusto te intentaré ayudar. :)
Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! Aunque ya resolví mi problema y estaba era en el .js no en el .html, debía declarar un $scope que me faltaba. Aun así gracias